# Java and Hadoop: Incompatible types with TextInputFormat

Tags: java, hadoop, extending

I am using hadoop core 0.20.2 and am running into an issue with incompatible types when trying to set the input format for my job.  I'm just trying to get a simple wordcount program running.

Here is my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    JobConf conf = new JobConf(Wordcount.class);
    conf.setJobName("wordcount");

    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
    conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

    conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
    conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

    JobClient.runJob(conf);
}
```

On the line `conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);` I am getting an error `incompatible types class<TextInputFormat> cannot be converted to Class<? extends InputFormat>`

When I take a look at the setInputFormat method I see:

```
public void setInputFormat(Class<? extends InputFormat> theClass) {
}
```

While I'm not 100% sure what `Class<? extends InputFormat> theClass` means I gather I must pass a class which extends InputFormat.  Please let me know if I am on the wrong track.

So when I take a look at the TextInputFormat class I see:

`public class TextInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<LongWritable, Text>`

So I'm passing a class which extends FileInputFormat and NOT InputFormat.

But I believe FileInputFormat extends InputFormat because I see in the declaration

`public abstract class FileInputFormat<K extends Object, V extends Object> extends InputFormat<K, V>`

Am I correct on why I am getting this error?  Or am I completely wrong and it is valid to pass a class which extends the correct class to any nth degree?

I am fairly new to Java and even newer to Hadoop.  I want to note that I am also getting errors on the lines

```
FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));
```

which read as "incompatible types: JobConf cannot be converted to Job".  I am aware 0.20.2 is not the latest version of Hadoop but I have to work with this version.  In new versions of Hadoop I've come across other ways to create a Job Configuration and am starting to think I am having issues because I may be referencing classes which we added after 0.20.2.

I am kind of reading online resources to help get a working copy, but I never know what version is being used.  So I may have mismatched code now.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the packages the classes come from.  You should be using a set of packages that have "mapred" as one level or another set that have "mapreduce" as one level.  I suspect that you're mixing packages and you need to use the TextInputFormat from the other package.

Comment: Spot on, thank you so much.  Are the two packages just different ways to go about the same thing?  Mapred and Mapreduce are similar by name and I take it they cannot be used with each other.

Comment: Mapred is an earlier version of the now current mapreduce.